# cpp: catch exception with ellipsis and see the information

Tags: c++, try-catch, ellipsis, variadic

I know that you can catch "all exceptions" and print the exception by

```
try
{
    //some code...
}catch(const std::exception& e) {
   cout << e.what();
}
```

but this is just for exceptions derived from std::exception.
I was wondering if there is a way to get some information from an ellipsis catch

```
try
{
    //some code...
}catch(...) {
   // ??
}
```

If the mechanism is the same as ellipsis for functions then I should be able to do something like casting the argument of the `va_list` and trying to call the `what()` method.

I haven't tried it yet but if someone knows the way I'd be excited to know how.

Comment: Have you ever wondered how it could work to call what() on an int when s.o. throws one ?

Comment: Obviously what I suggested wouldn't always work. I'm looking for a way to get something from it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry, you can't do that. You can only access the exception object in a `catch` block for a specific exception type.

Answer (score 9):

From C++11 and onwards, you can use `std::current_exception` &c:

```
std::exception_ptr p;
try {
    
} catch(...) {
    p = std::current_exception();
}
```

You can then "inspect" `p` by taking casts &c, albeit not in a portable way.

In earlier standards there is no portable way of intersecting the exception at a `catch(...)` site, other than re-throwing it with `throw;`.

Comment: what is the `&c` you wrote?

Comment: That's new to me (the &c) :)
Can you show in your answer what can you do with this `exception_ptr` (what is the advantage)?

Comment: You can't get any details out of `std::exception_ptr`, you can only rethrow it.